# Can't get the Jquery color UI to work on Hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm new to jquery, I would likt the background color for my a tag to change on the hover event.

So far, this is what I have  and I can't get is to respond....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".form_layout_button_box a").hover(
    function(){
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#D8E4BC'},'slow')
    },
    function() {
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#C4D79B'},'slow')
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my mistake, I didn't call the query properly,

I've wrote :

```
 function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#D8E4BC'},'slow')
},
```

In the above example, I neede to replace the $(this) with $($(this)) and the function work.

```
function(){
       $($(this)).animate({backgroundColor: '#C4D79B'},'fast')
},
```

Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to apply CSS properties to an element. As for the animate you could try using [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

With hover the color will remain on mouseout. So I prefer to use mouseover and mouseout. You could also do some if / else logic if you want to use .hover().

```
$(".form_layout_button_box a").hover(function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#D8E4BC');
});
```

**-or-**

```
$(".form_layout_button_box a").mouseover(function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#D8E4BC');
});


$(".form_layout_button_box a").mouseout(function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#333');
});
```

**DEMO USING MOUSEOVER AND MOUSEOUT:**

http://jsfiddle.net/GZFAZ/3/

**EQUIVALENT T0 THIS IN CSS:**

This would give you the same affect with pure CSS.

```
.form_layout_button_box a       {background-color:#666;}
.form_layout_button_box a:hover {background-color:#D8E4BC;}
```